# How do I create a folder in the Files app on my iPhone? (not on iCloud)

Tags: iphone

When I open the files app on my iPhone there's no option to create a folder. I'm stuck with the defaults of Keynote, Numbers and Pages. How do I create my own folders?

Answer (score 3):

Creating a new independent folder in the "Files app" does not appears to be possible without iCloud with exception of creating sub folders in the existing apps like Keynote, Numbers and Pages.